# int return type in java

Tags: java, int, return

Below is the code snippet , where I am confused .The return type of method is int , so the method can not return null.But , when I uncomment 1st return statement and comment 2nd return statement, method's doesn't show any error not even warning.
I am confused what is the reason behind that.I am using java version 7.

```
 protected int calculateLogicalPageRangeForTitles(String logicalpage) throws Exception {
     //return StringUtils.isNumeric(logicalpage) ? Integer.parseInt(logicalpage) : null;
     return null;
 }
```

Comment: Doesn't compile here, for 2 reasons: no type specified for logicalpage, incompatible return type.

Comment: Your method wouldn't compile (`logicalpage` has no type and later you use `logicalPage` - uppercase P).  But when you uncomment the first line, the return is either `Integer.parseInt(logicalPage)` or `0` both are or return valid `int`s...

Comment: sorry for my mistaken code snippet .I've edited .
I applogize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is legal and compiles.

See Java Spec:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25

> If one of the second and third operands is of the null type and the
>   type of the other is a reference type, then the type of the
>   conditional expression is that reference type.

This means, the result of the ?: will be an Integer, which will be unboxed to int. This unboxing will throw a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

This statement only returns a `int`. `parseInt` returns an `int` and `0` is an `int`

```
return StringUtils.isNumeric(logicalPage) ? Integer.parseInt(logicalPage) : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

The first `return` statement

```
return StringUtils.isNumeric(logicalPage) ? Integer.parseInt(logicalPage) : 0;
```

always returns an `int` value (or an exception). The method [`Integer.parseInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) returns a primitive `int` value as well. So no errors or warnings are shown.

The second statement, however,

```
return null;
```

tries to return a `null` value for the *primitive* return type `int`, which is not valid and thus leads to a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

That's because [parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) returns an int (primitive type), which matches your method's signature.

`null`, on the other hand, is not compatible with a primitive int, that's why you have an error.

Answer (score 0):

Because your first statement will always return an `int`. So it compiles.

But second statement returns `null` which is of `Object` type. This will compile if your return type is `Integer` instead of `int`

Answer (score 0):

int is a primitive... therefore it has to have a value. null is a value telling us that the reference (to a class) does not refer to any instance.

Answer (score 0):

Your first line is not valid either. if it turns out to be false and it tries to return the `null` value, an exception is raised.

If you write the code out to a verbose if statement it will give you the error. Like:

```
if (StringUtils.isNumeric(logicalpage){
    return Integer.parseInt(logicalpage);
}else{
    return null;
}
```